# Manual installation SciPy, NumPy, MatPlotlib (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I want to install SciPy, NumPy and MatplotLib globally so that the libraries can be accessed from network computers. Basically it should be in some network drive without full installation of the libraries on each remote computer.
Now I copied the site-package directory from one working installation into the network drive, but not surprisingly I now get "DLL load failed" (multiarray) errors when trying to import scipy from remote computers. I suppose there are DLLs missing.

What would be the easiest solution to this problem? Does anyone know which DLLs I need to copy to all remote computers or can I even have these DLLs on the network drive too inside PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 1):

In the docs, see : http://docs.python.org/install/index.html

```
"Alternate installation: Windows (the prefix scheme)"
"Modifying Python’s Search Path"
"Custom Installation"
```

may help you. 
There is also the PYTHONHOME var used during install.

But frankly, I'm afraid you will not succeed doing this because the packages are compiled during installation, and compilers depends on CPU, vary from one PC to another (one has the minGW, other has the intel, third one has the borland ... ) and I think python packages do not use as much place, so that it makes sense to install on each computer, more than trying to deal with ONE install for everyone.
Unless you make sure everybody has the same C and fortran compilers... but even so, it will not be easy, i'm afraid.